# How do I displays the keys of keyboard on screen to demonstrate my operation?

Tags: macos

A [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/06I63_p-2A4?t=819) (The link starts at 13′39″) displays the keys of keyboard on screen while the narrator operating. Is it a feature of screen recorder or something else?

Not necessarily the app built into macOS, any third-party app could do the job would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Not something I've seen before. It's certainly not built into macOS. [I know that doesn't *really* help ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as modifier keys are concerned, it is built in MacOs.

System Preferences / Accessibility / Keyboard / Activate keys with automatic hold